# Realmd / SSSD Sudo performance issues

Tags: active-directory, sssd, rhel8

I have bunch of RHEL8.6 machines and i need user authentication via Active Directory.

I got machines added to AD-domain with Realmd, made user groups, restricted access to user groups and enabled Sudo for those groups.

However, i'm facing some lag/delay(3-10 seconds) when running commands with sudo.

AD has about 200-250 users total. At the moment there is only one(1) user group with 3 users who has access to RHEL-servers.

All required packages listed with:

```
realm discover domain.com
```

is installed.

Is there something i can do in RHEL side to "tune" sudo performance?
I would prefer to make changes at RHEL-side because AD is not familiar to me at all.

I'm not very familiar with SSSD or anything related to that so i appreciate every tip.

Thanks already

Answer (score 0):

The question is *old* but it may solve the day for someone.
I would check first for DNS/LDAP latency issues. Every login is checked against AD every time, so this causes some latency. RedHat also Recommends setting up a site if root DC is geographically distant: check `ad_site` option: https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/5-sssd-sudo/

If you already have a site, `sssd` may not connect to it directly. This is what `ad_site` achieves.

Comment: Actually i have been talking with redhat support about this and got this solved. I will try to remember to post sssd.conf file here as like you said: ”it may solve the day for someone.”